# simple bash script for collecting logs

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, unix, sftp

I'm new with BASH scripting and I need a little help if it's possible.

Let's say there's a UNIX server from which I want to gather some simple log events (let's say .txt files). Let's say log events need to be collected every 15 minutes. What's the best way to compose a bash script, and in addition - use available Linux commands with SSH/SFTP.

This is what I found so far.

`$ sftp remote_username@server_ip_or_hostname`

To download a single file from the remote server, use the get command:

`get filename.txt`

To download a directory from the remote system, use the recursive -r option:

`get -r remote_directory`

How can I set it up to collect every 15 minutes? Maybe to write a script to collect data and then the second script using Cronjob to execute the first one?

Sorry for these questions but I'm pretty new here.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do the whole job as a bash script.
For example look into [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html) to collect log events.
From there you can trigger small scripts, or send mails.

Example configuration to trigger a script if your regexp matches:

```
check file mylog with path /var/log/my.log
    noalert root@localhost

    if match 'myregexp' then exec "/etc/myscrips/monit/myscript.sh parameter1 parameter2"
            as uid myuser and gid mygroup
```